# How to add a dark mode toggle to a Flutter app using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, sharedpreferences

I'm building a Flutter app and I want to add a dark mode toggle that allows the user to switch between light and dark themes. I've heard that the SharedPreferences package can be used to store user preferences, but I'm not sure how to implement it in my app.

Can someone provide a example or some guidance on how to use SharedPreferences to store and retrieve a boolean value that indicates whether dark mode is enabled? I'd also appreciate any tips on how to conditionally apply a dark theme to the app based on this value.

Here's the code that I've been working on so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  bool _isDarkModeEnabled = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadDarkModePreference();
  }

  void _loadDarkModePreference() async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final isDarkModeEnabled = prefs.getBool('isDarkModeEnabled') ?? false;
    setState(() {
      _isDarkModeEnabled = isDarkModeEnabled;
    });
  }

  void _toggleDarkMode(bool newValue) async {
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setBool('isDarkModeEnabled', newValue);
    setState(() {
      _isDarkModeEnabled = newValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: _isDarkModeEnabled
          ? ThemeData.dark()
          : ThemeData.light(),
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Flutter Demo'),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Dark mode is ${_isDarkModeEnabled ? 'enabled' : 'disabled'}.',
              ),
              Switch(
                value: _isDarkModeEnabled,
                onChanged: _toggleDarkMode,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: your current snippet should be wroking ig